# Can any leather crafters tell me what tool this is?

Tags: leather, tool-identification

My friend began taking up leatherwork. This tool came in a kit he bought. We know what everything else is except for this piece, and a reverse Google image search came up short. Just showed us bullets and pencils. Anybody know what this is and what it's for?

[image]

Comment: Hi Kyle, I think this is for punching holes in the leather, but I'm sure there's someone here who's more familiar with leatherworking. Welcome to Arts & Crafts!

Comment: Does it open up on the grooves? It looks to me like there might be more parts or other options when opening up.

Comment: It doesn't open up anywhere but the brass plating can freely spin on the axis of the tool.

Comment: What's that writing on it... it looks like "DRY LEATHER TOOL"? Is there more on the other side? Why does the bottom look like we can see through it? The surface has different colours which suggests that it's been used, I'd vote for it being a dip-pen for marking and would point to an apparent ink stain near the bottom of the grooves.

Answer (score 5):

Awls are typically used for punching holes into objects, awls come in different styles. This one in particular, if you look at the back end, looks very durable, and able to be hammered on the back without issues. So it is able to push through thick leather easily.

Standard image of an awl:
[image]

Awl being used to punch hole:
[image]

Awl being used in practice to lace leather:
[image]

Sources:
https://hausoftools.com/blogs/news/tools-of-the-trade-tools-for-leather-working

https://www.instructables.com/how-to-prepare-leather-for-sewing/

Comment: My leather awl was hastily made from a 6" nail ground to a point just like that. For the little leatherwork (and similar - I've just made a belt from a bike tyre) I do, pushing is much more likely than hammering so the ergonomic shape is worthwhile

Comment: The photo in the question looks like the tip is too fine to serve as a centre punch that gets hit. It wouldn't last long at all.

Comment: Yea, that may be correct, it probably would break off.

Comment: The back/top end is flat and wider than the rest of the tool. Why would you hit down on the fine tip? Or do you mean to hit the tip into the leather? The craftsmanship of the tool is pretty sturdy and has a surprising amount of weight to it. I also noticed the brass plating seems to spin uniformly on the axis or shaft of the tool. Does that help with the description?

Comment: Yes, you would hit the tip into the leather to create a hole. By hitting it on the back-end. Which is why it is sturdy/heavy weighed for that purpose.

Comment: It's not nearly sharp (or amenable to sharpening) to be an awl, and it lacks the comfortable handle. When I started buying that sort of thing I got a (welcome) lecture from the supplier (Leprevo in the UK) on the correct technique used to sharpen it.

Answer (score 3):

To me the tip looks just like the tool I use to apply edge coat.  The little indentations hold the edge coat as you apply it. I’m assuming the pointed end spins?  If so that’s what you have, a tool to apply an edge coat.  An edge coat is applied as a thick coating to finish any edge on your project.  Before that takes place you would burnish the edge with a chemical, gum tragacanth. I use fiebings for the gum and edge coat.  Or you can simply coat an edge using water, then using a clean cotton cloth rub the edges treated with water for just a few second, the edge will get glossy.  Then apply the edge coat.  Hope I nailed it!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a multi tool, the very point could be used as a awl as previously said, the part with the indentations to aply all sorts of compounds to the edge end last but not least the end portion resambles a burnishing tool. So its probably a "jack of all trades" tool as commonly found on those kits, its probably not the best for each feature but certainly can be a nice tool to have

Answer (score 3):

It's a Leathercraft 5-in-one Multi Tool.

https://www.etsy.com/sg-en/listing/810136661/leathercraft-5-in-1-multi-tool-3ea

It's supposed to pull apart and... do various clever things, but quite frankly I see nothing to recommend it over a traditional awl etc. which has a proper handle.

Comment: After having looked at the picture you linked to I can just confirm ... it certainly looks 100% the same :)